# Wait for a Scala Future to complete and continue with the next one

Tags: multithreading, scala, akka-stream

I have a list of 500,000 elements and a queue with 20 consumers. The messages are processed at different speeds (1, 15, 30, 60 seconds; 3, 50 min; 3, 16 hours, or more. 24 hours is the timeout). I need the consumer's response in order to do some processing over the data. I am going to use Scala `Future` for this and event-based `onComplete`.

In order not to flood the queue, I want to send first 30 messages to the queue: 20 will be picked by the consumers and 10 will be waiting in the queue. When one of the `Future`s is complete, I want to send another message to the queue. Can you give me an idea how to achieve this? Can this be done with Akka Streams?

This is wrong, I just want to give you an idea of what I want:

```
private def sendMessage(ids: List[String]): Unit = {
  val id = ids.head

  val futureResult = Future {
    //send id among some message to the queue
  }.map { result =>
    //process the response
  }

  futureResult.onComplete { _ =>
    sendMessage(ids.tail)
  }
}

def migrateAll(): Unit = {
  val ids: List[String] = //get IDs from the DB

  sendMessage(ids)
}
```

Comment: It's very easy to do with Monix.  https://monix.io/docs/2x/tutorials/parallelism.html#observablemapasync

Comment: akka-streams would be perfect for your scenario and it wouldn't take you long to pick up it's DSL if you are already somewhat familiar with Scala (it also has a Java DSL). Akka streams has built-in back-pressure facilities which should take care of not flooding your downstream queue, but if you want more fine-grained control of the rate at which you process data it also has throttling facilities - https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/stream/stream-quickstart.html#time-based-processing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a simple example with Akka Streams that models your use case.

Let's define the processing as a method that takes a `String` and returns a `Future[String]`:

```
def process(id: String): Future[String] = ???
```

Then we create a `Source` from a `List` of 500,000 `String` elements and use [`mapAsync`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.html#mapAsync[T](parallelism:Int)(f:Out=%3Escala.concurrent.Future[T]):FlowOps.this.Repr[T]) to feed the elements to the processing method. The level of parallelism is set to 20, meaning that no more than 20 `Future`s will be running at any point in time. As each `Future` is completed, we perform additional processing and print the result:

```
Source((1 to 500000).map(_.toString).toList)
  .mapAsync(parallelism = 20)(process)
  // do something with the result of the Future; here we create a new string
  //   that begins with "Processed: "
  .map(s => s"Processed: $s")
  .runForeach(println)
```

You can read more about `mapAsync` in the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/stream/stream-integrations.html#integrating-with-external-services).

Comment: If the downstream order of elements is not important you can use `mapAsyncUnordered`, `mapAsync` was a blocker for me.

Answer (score 2):

That is a code I used for such tasks

```
class RateLimiter(semaphore: Semaphore) {
  def runBlocking[T](action: => Future[T]): Future[T] = {
    semaphore.acquire()
    val started = try {
      action
    }
    catch {
      case NonFatal(th) => {
        semaphore.release()
        throw th
      }
    }

    started.andThen {
      case _ => semaphore.release()
    }(ExecutionContext.Implicits.global)
  }
}

val rateLimiter = new RateLimiter(new Semaphore(20))
val tasks = (1 to 100)
val futures: Seq[Future[Int]] = tasks.map(i => rateLimiter.runBlocking(Future{
    i * 2
  }(ExecutionContext.Implicits.global)))
futures.foreach(f => Await.result(f, Duration.Inf))
```

It is not perfect since it blocks in 2 places (in the semaphore and in 'Await') and holds all futures in memory (it can be avoided).

But it works on production :)

Comment: I should document more about Semaphore, it might be useful in some circumstances.